Continuously Differentiable Function with uncountably many flat regions
I'm struggling to answer this:

Does there exist a continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\nabla f)^{-1}(0)$ (i.e. the set of "flat" regions) has uncountably many connected components?

I can see that $(\nabla f)^{-1}(0)$ must be compact, so I thought maybe if I constructed a cover of open sets for each component somehow I could show that the result holds but I've not been able to do so.

Can you think of a compact subset of $[0,1]$ which has continuum of connected components?

I'm a little confused by the phrasing - what is meant by "continuum of connected components"?

You can't use a cover by uncountably many open sets to prove your statement since any open set in $\Bbb R$ (and hence in $[0,1]$) is a (at most) countable union of open intervals

It’s perhaps misleading to say “flat regions” rather than “critical points.” It suggests entire intervals on which the graph is flat.

Do you know what cardinality means? Then what I said means: the set of connected components has cardinality of continuum.

I understand now, thank you.

I'm confused as to why this question has now been closed.

If you can construct a continuous function such that its zero set has uncountable many connected components, then taking $f$ to be an indefinite integral of such function solves your problem.
But such a function is easy to find: for example, a function which sends $x \in [0, 1]$ to the distance from a Cantor set $C \subset [0, 1]$. Every point of $C$ is a connected component, and $C$ is uncountable.

Do you mean to say continuous function?
